# Gitlab can't start postgresql, redis and sidekiq after upgrade from 7.11 to 8.0

Tags: postgresql, redis, gitlab, sidekiq

I updated from Gitlab 7.11 to 8.0. Due to lack of space on the root partition, I uninstalled Gitlab 7 via

```
sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
```

and installed 8 via

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

I had a few other problems that I found solutions for online and have finally managed to get 8 up and running. I have confirmed the data is still there. The problem is I can't start the postgresql, redis and sidekiq services via `gitlab-ctl`:

```
administrator@development:/var/opt/gitlab$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart
ok: run: gitlab-git-http-server: (pid 15873) 1s
ok: run: logrotate: (pid 15879) 0s
ok: run: nginx: (pid 15972) 0s
timeout: run: postgresql: (pid 2191) 7089s
timeout: run: redis: (pid 21277) 52584s, got TERM
timeout: run: sidekiq: (pid 5200) 1882s, got TERM
ok: run: unicorn: (pid 16308) 0s
```

I can however start postgresql via:

```
sudo su - gitlab-psql -c \
  '/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/'
```

and redis via:

```
sudo su -s '/bin/sh' -c \
  '/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server /var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.conf' gitlab-redis
```

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04. How can I get Gitlab to start/stop postgresql, redis and sidekiq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are most likely occuring because of the **runsvdir** service failing using:

```
ps auxw
```

The errors or warnings will be pretty blatent, in my case:

*runsvdir -P /opt/gitlab/service log: ar/log/gitlab/sidekiq: file does not exist svlogd: pausing: unable to rename c*

Ensure your machine has enough space using:

```
df /
```

Delete files which maybe taking up space. e.g. Logs, backups, etc... in my case I had 25GB of backups and only a 30GB drive. My / was 100% in use and not allowing my logs to rotate.

Stop gitlab using:

```
gitlab-ctl stop
```

Manually kill any left over processes. Use ps auxw to identify the left over processes and kill -9 them.

Restart gitlab using:

```
gitlab-ctl start
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! it did work actually, i did `pgrep -f postgres | xargs kill -9` and repeated that for sidekiq and redis  after I did `gitlab-ctl stop` and then did `gitlab-ctl start` and everything went up just well (gitlab 11.9 - 11.10)

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue where i saw errors like

> file "current" could not be renamed

finally resolved by killing all the `runsv` and `svlogd` processes, then `gitlab-ctl restart`

root cause for me was the following change:

> `gitlab-ctl stop && mv /var/log/gitlab{,_BAK} && mount /dev/gitlab-vg/logs-lv /var/log/gitlab && gitlab-ctl start`

... effectively replacing path "/var/log/gitlab/" with a mounted volume

so, changing the pointers out from under Gitlab, more specifically runit, did cause that process manager to fail restarting services like sidekiq, workhorse, nginx, etc.  Restarting with `gitlab-ctl restart` did not resolve it, since runsv,svlogd apparently are not also restarted (restart of the entire system, however, *would have fixed this*).

I should also say that this issue did not manifest itself until the day after change to `/var/log/gitlab/`. As i understand it, not until then did svlogd yet try to move/rename the log files (eg: */var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current*).  I should've noticed this, since the "new" log files in the mounted path were not written to immediately after replacement.

One might encounter the same issue from simply implementing logrotate (anything affecting those file pointers outside svlogd/runit) -- even if you restart gitlab-omnibus.

Answer (score 1):

In that situation can help you

```
systemctl stop gitlab-runsvdir && systemctl start gitlab-runsvdir
```

Answer (score -1):

After a couple of hours of trying and new issues popping up, I ended up downgrading to 7.11 and upgrading to 7.12, 7.13, 7.14 and eventually 8.0 in individual steps. No issues after the upgrade.